# How can I find with 2 relative object properties of array in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

So a user has 2 users whom he follows:

```
"following": [{
        "userid": {
            "$oid": "60a933ebb35b4b3c788ee37c"        // say user A
        },
        "time": 1622147753992                       // when this user was followed (new Date().getTime())
    }, {
        "userid": {
            "$oid": "60a932edb35b4b3c788ee377"                   // user B
        },
        "time": 1622155516968
    }]
```

Im trying to query the notifications which this user will get from userA and userB dated after the time when they were followed.

here's what I've tried after getting the above list of followers:

```
notificationModel.find({$and: [
                    {userid: following.userid},
                    {time: {$gte: following.time}}
                ]}).then(...
```

This query gives 0 results and no error.
As each user has his own moment when he was followed, how can I compare a userid and its corresponding time with notification userid and time?

Note: there can be any number of entries in following array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `following` is an array so `following.userid` and `following.time` will be `undefined`. To make it work, you can create a conditions array from that array first then use it with [$or](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) to query. Something likes:

```
let conditions = following.map(e => ({
  userid: e.userid,
  time: {$gte: e.time}
}));

notificationModel.find({ $or: conditions });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your userId and time are inside an array. So you need to use `$elemMatch` or dot annotation. When u do the projection `following.$` it will give u the first element of the array as doc says  *"you can specify the projection to return the first element that match the query condition on the array field"* [Doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#definition)

```
db.collection.find({
  following: {
    "$elemMatch": {
      userid: "60a933ebb35b4b3c788ee37c",
      time: {
        $gte: 1622147753992
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "following.$": 1
})
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NXAhFjQuxGa)

---

But if the result has multiple elements inside the array, you need to go with aggregations

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      following: {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$following",
          cond: {
            $and: [
              {  $eq: [ "$$this.userid", "60a933ebb35b4b3c788ee37c" ] },
              { "$gte": [ "$$this.time", 1622147753992 ] }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/MsgAXAD_UC4)

Comment: No, you can use for  multiple elements also